# Intersection of monotone classes empty

Tags: probability, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I've learned and checked the definition of monotone classes in a book and several online ressources (and looked on Math Stack Exchange without finding exactly the answer to the question I have) but I might have part of the definition wrong :

> For a given set X a monotone class M is a non-empty family of P(X)
> which is closed under countable increasing unions and countable
> decreasing intersections

Let's say I have X = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, and M1={{1}, {1,2}, {1,2,3}}, M2={{8,9,10}, {9,10}, {10}}.

Then Φ=M1∩M2=∅, so Φ is empty, and therefore, not a monotone class. But the intersection of any collection of monotone classes should be another monotone class, so where is the mistake please ?

Comment: neither $M_1$ nor $M_2$ is a monotone class. They are not closed under countable increasing unions.

Comment: A monotone class $M$ contains both $\emptyset$ and the total space $X$: The empty set $\emptyset$ is a countable subset of $M$, and $X=\bigcap\emptyset$ and $\emptyset=\bigcup\emptyset$.